# Null pointer when trying to access POJO attribute

Tags: java, android, gson, retrofit

I am using Retrofit 2 to consume an JSON API, I have the following JSON structure

```
{
    "data": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Josh"
    }
}
```

My `User` POJO looks like:

```
public class User {

    private String name;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

And my User interface

```
@GET("/api/v1/me")
Call<User> me();
```

But I when I try and do `response.body().getName()` I get a null pointer exception.

The code which is making the request

```
UserService userService = ServiceGenerator.createService(UserService.class)

    Call<User> call = userService.me();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Response<User> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
            if(response.isSuccess()) {
                Log.i("user", response.body().getName().toString());
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable t) {
            Log.i("hello", t.getMessage());
        }
    });
```

Comment: Your name property is inside the data property , and hence deserialization is not proper

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Yup this is what I thought, what is the correct way to get it out of the data property from a POJO?

Comment: You could make another pojo , having Data object property there...So first from response you get Data, from that you fetch the name and id.

Comment: please see the updated comment.

Comment: @cafebabe1991 Can you give a code example?

Comment: @joshuahornby10 , I have added an example below.

Comment: Did it help ? @joshuahornby10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create the POJO classes as follows:

POJO for json response:

```
public class User {


    private Data data;


    public Data getData() {
        return data;
    }


    public void setData(Data data) {
        this.data = data;
    }

}
```

POJO for internal Data:

```
public class Data {


    private int id;

    private String name;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }


    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }


    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

Than use response.body().getData().getName() to access name in response.

Comment: Hi..How to Handle if the Data Object is returned as  null from the API, then Accessing the getData will throw a null pointer Exception

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Data {

    private User data;

    public String getData() {
        return data;
    }

    public void setName(User data) {
        this.data = data;
    }
}
```

> ```
> Access it like this
> ```

```
public void onResponse(Response<Data> response, Retrofit retrofit) {
        if(response.isSuccess()) {
            Log.i("user", response.body().getData().getName().toString());
        }

    }
```